# Pyschools: Write a recursive function returning a sting of numbers from arguments a to b

Tags: python, recursion

Write a recursive function numbersInbetween(start, end) that takes in two numbers and returns a common-separated string with all the numbers in between the start and end number inclusive of both numbers.

My attempt:

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if  b == 0:
        return "Invalid"
    if a == b:
        return '%d' % (a)
    else:
        return '%s,%s' % (a, numbersInbetween(a+1,b))
```

All inputs return the expected result, however pyschools returns "Private test cases failed".

Could you please point out my errors here, i have tried numerous variations with little success. Thanks

Comment: *pyschools returns "Private test cases failed".*?

Comment: So...what's the base case?  Can I start at any number and end at any other number?  What are the constraints?  What do some samples of valid output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Looking [here](http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s11-q10)**, it seems like your problem is here:

```
if b == 0:
```

If you enter b as a non-zero value less than `a`:

```
...
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in numbersInbetween
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in numbersInbetween
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in numbersInbetween
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Therefore, change `if b == 0` to `if b < a`:

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if b < a:
        return "Invalid"
    if a == b:
        return '%d' % (a)
    else:
        return '%s,%s' % (a, numbersInbetween(a+1,b))
```